# How to set custom TinyMCE format style as default?

Tags: tinymce

I've created custom TinyMCE formats. In function I have something like this:

```
$style_formats = array(
  array(
    'title' => 'Akapit',
    'block' => 'p',
    'classes' => 'e-paragraph',
  ),
```

works fine, but Im trying to set one of the style as default. How can I do that?

Comment: You mean whatever you write in the editor should be wrapped up by p tag with class e-paragraph?

Comment: Exactly. By default.